# mysql --protocol=tcp changes login behavior

Tags: mysql, tcp

I'm testing databus from LinkedIn which populates a MySQL database for user `or_test` and propagates changes.  They have a script which invokes mysql `--protocol=tcp`.  On my local MySQL setup this fails with access denied.  When I omit `--protocol=tcp` option I can execute the commands fine.  But even when the user is created, and access to it is granted, and login without the above option is fine, coming back with the option fails.  The Java client apparently uses a similar connectivity and fails with access denied.  I have `bind-address=0.0.0.0` set and can telnet to the port.  I gave grants to the `'or_test'@'localhost'` user, as well as `'or_test'@'%'` What's the potential interaction of this option in causing access denied?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem of mysql permission. Run "flush privileges" in Mysql.

If still doesn't work. Databus creates two users one with or_test@localhost and other with or_test@127.0.0.1. Delete the second user and then "flush privileges". It should work now.